# RxJava unit testing - Observable not emitting events in tests

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm testing a view model which has the following definition:

```
class PostViewModel(private val postApi: PostApi): ViewModel() {

    private val _post: PublishSubject<Post> = PublishSubject.create()
    val postAuthor: Observable<String> = _post.map { it.author }

    fun refresh(): Completable {
        return postApi.getPost() // returns Single<Post>
            .doOnSuccess {
                _post.onNext(it)
            }
            .ignoreElement()
        }
    }
}
```

My fragment then displays the post author by subscribing to `viewModel.postAuthor` in its `onActivityCreated` and calling and subscribing to `refresh()` whenever the user wants an updated post and everything is fine and dandy.

The issue I'm running into is trying to verify this behaviour in a unit test: specifically, I am unable to get `postAuthor` to emit an event in my testing environment.

My test is defined as follows:

```
    @Test
        fun `When view model is successfully refreshed, display postAuthor`() {


        val post = Post(...)


        whenever(mockPostApi.getPost().thenReturn(Single.just(post))
            viewModel.refresh()
                .andThen(viewModel.postAuthor)
                .test()
                .assertValue { it == "George Orwell" }
        }
```

The test fails due to no values or errors being emitted, even though I can verify through the debugger that the mock does in-fact return the `Post` as expected. Is there something obvious that I'm missing, or am I completely wrong in my testing approach?

Answer (score 3):

`viewModel.postAuthor` is a hot-observable. It emits value when you call `_post.onNext(it)`.

Unlike a cold-observable, the late subscribers cannot receive the values that got emitted before they subscribe. 
So in your case I think the `viewModel.postAuthor` is subscribed after you call `viewModel.refresh()`, so it cannot receive the value.

Answer (score 0):

The observable could be emitting on a different thread so that's why it's empty when the test is checking the values/errors.

You could try forcing your observable to emit on the same thread. Depending on which scheduler you're using, it'd be something like:

```
RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }
```